# Bash Script to Prepend a Single Random Character to All Files In a Folder

Tags: bash, shell, random

I have an audio sample library with thousands of files. I would like to shuffle/randomize the order of these files. Can someone provide me with a bash script/line that would prepend a single random character to all files in a folder (including files in sub-folders). I do not want to prepend a random character to any of the folder names though.

---

**Example:**
Kickdrum73.wav
Kickdrum SUB.wav
Kick808.mp3

**Renamed to:**
f_Kickdrum73.wav
!_Kickdrum SUB.wav
4_Kick808.mp3

---

If possible, I would like to be able to run this script more than once, but on subsequent runs, it just changes the randomly prepended character instead of prepending a new one.

Some of my attempts:

```
find ~/Desktop/test -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 bash -c 'mv "$0" "a${0}"'    
find ~/Desktop/test/ -type f -exec mv -v {} $(cat a {}) \;   
find ~/Desktop/test/ -type f -exec echo -e "Z\n$(cat !)" > !Hat 15.wav    
for file in *; do    
    mv -v "$file" $RANDOM_"$file"    
done
```

Note: I am running on macOS.

---

Latest attempt using code from mr. fixit:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 999 -not -name ".*" |
cut -c 3- - |
while read F; do
    randomCharacter="${F:2:1}"
    if [ $randomCharacter == '_' ]; then
        new="${F:1}"
    else
        new="_$F"
    fi
    fileName="`basename $new`"
    newFilename="`jot -r -c $fileName 1 A Z`"
    filePath="`dirname $new`"
    newFilePath="$filePath$newFilename"
    mv -v "$F" "$newFilePath"
done
```

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Instead of randomly renaming all files and giving your player/tool an alphabetic list, have you considered just giving your player/tool a randomly shuffled list?

Comment: shuf -i MIN-MAX -n COUNT

Comment: @thatotherguy I'm not sure what you mean. By renaming the files like this I effectively am giving the player/tool a randomly shuffled list. I don't know of a way to shuffle the files in my player/tool it just displays them alphabetically.

Comment: @Cyrus I don't think any of the things that I tried would be helpful considering this is most likely just a one-liner and I am not an experience Bash user.

Comment: It's very helpful because that puts the question in the "I'm programming something but got stuck" category that SO supports, rather than the "Here are my requirements, please write the code for me" category that it tries to avoid.

Comment: @thatotherguy Okay that's fair. I just added a few of my attempts in the original question. I can assure you that I have been poking around the internet for the past few days trying different things. Cyrus' reply just seemed kind of curt and unhelpful to me.

Comment: @RamanSailopal Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately that did not work for me. The terminal spit out "shuf: command not found". I am running on a Mac, do I need to install something to use shuf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my first answer, enhanced to do sub-directories.

Put the following in file `randomize`

```
if [[ $# != 1 || ! -d "$1" ]]; then
  echo "usage: $0 <path>"
else
  find $1 -type f -not -name ".*" |
    while read F; do
      FDIR=`dirname "$F"`
      FNAME=`basename "$F"`
      char2="${FNAME:1:1}"
      if [ $char2 == '_' ]; then
        new="${FNAME:1}"
      else
        new="_$FNAME"
      fi
      new=`jot -r -w "%c$new" 1 A Z`
      echo mv "$F" "${FDIR}/${new}"
    done
fi
```

Set the permissions with `chmod a+x randomize`.

Then call it with `randomize your/path`.

It'll echo the commands required to rename everything, so you can examine them to ensure they'll work for you. If they look right, you can remove the `echo` from the 3rd to last line and rerun the script.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much. Love how this can be run more than once too and it replaces the prepended character too.

Answer (score 0):

`cd ~/Desktop/test`, then

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -not -name ".*" |
    cut -c 3- - |
    while read F; do
        char2="${F:2:1}"
        if [ $char2 == '_' ]; then
            new="${F:1}"
        else
            new="_$F"
        fi
        new=`jot -r -w "%c$new" 1 A Z`
        mv "$F" "$new"
    done
```

`find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -not -name ".*"` will get all the files in the current directory, but not the hidden files (names starting with '.')

`cut -c 3- -`  will strip the first 2 chars from the name. `find` outputs paths, and the `./` gets in the way of processing prefixes.

`while read VAR; do <stuff>; done` is a way to deal with one line at a time

`char2="${VAR:2:1}` sets a variable `char2` to the 2nd character of the variable `VAR`.

`if - then - else` sets `new` to the filename, either preceded by `_` or with the previous random character stripped off.

`jot -r -w "%c$new" 1 A Z` tacks random 1 character from A-Z onto the beginning of `new`

`mv old new` renames the file

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This is really really close to what I need! The problem seems to be that the random character is being appended to the whole path and not just the filename at the end of the path. Example: rename 7602-Hats/Closed/Closed Hihats - 024.wav to K_7602-Hats/Closed/Closed Hihats - 024.wav: No such file or directory

Comment: sorry, i missed the "including subdirectories" portion in your original statement. there's a relatively simple fix, involving `basename` and `dirname`, but i don't have time at the moment to code it up.

Comment: No worries, I'll keep trying and post a solution if I get it. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it all in bash and there are several ways to approach it. The first is simply creating an array of `letters` containing whatever letters you want to use as a prefix and then generating a random number to use to choose the element of the array, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

letters=({0..9} {A..Z} {a..z})                      ## array with [0-9] [A-Z] [a-z]

for i in *; do
    num=$(($RANDOM % 63))                           ## generate number
    ## remove echo to actually move file
    echo "mv \"$i\" \"${letters[num]}_$i\""         ## move file
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

Current the script outputs the changes it would make, you must remove the `echo "..."` surrounding the `mv` command and fix the escaped quotes to actually have it apply changes:

```
$ bash ../randprefix.sh
mv "Kick808.mp3" "4_Kick808.mp3"
mv "Kickdrum SUB.wav" "h_Kickdrum SUB.wav"
mv "Kickdrum73.wav" "l_Kickdrum73.wav"
```

You can also do it by generating a random number representing the ASCII character between `48` (character `'0'`) through `126` (character `'~'`), excluding '`backtick`'), and then converting the random number to an ASCII character and prefix the filename with it, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *; do
    num=$((($RANDOM % 78) + 48))                         ## generate number for '0' - '~'
    letter=$(printf "\\$(printf '%03o' "$num")")         ## letter from number
    while [ "$letter" = '`' ]; do                        ## exclude '`'
        num=$((($RANDOM % 78) + 48))                     ## generate number
        letter=$(printf "\\$(printf '%03o' "$num")")
    done
    ## remove echo to actually move file
    echo "mv \"$i\" \"${letter}_$i\""                    ## move file
done
```

(similar output, all punctuation other than `backtick` is possible)

In each case you will want to place the script in your path or call it from within the directory you want to move the file in (you split split `dirname` and `basename` and join them back together to make the script callable passing the directory to search as an argument -- that is left to you)